# Updating windows 10 to 1511, dual booting with Xubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, xubuntu

I have been dual-booting Xubuntu and Windows 10 since windows 10 came out as the final version a few months ago.  I installed Xubuntu after Windows and made Grub the bootloader. I am trying to get Windows 10 to upgrade to the newest version (10586.17), but it fails after I restart to finish the installation. I am trying to figure out if it is the windows installation itself, or the fact that I dual-boot which confuses Windows when it tries to finish the update. On my work computer I have windows 10 only, which updated without any problems. I tried to set a virtual machine to test whether it was windows 10 but could not get it to do anything.

I am willing to do re-install Xubuntu after I update windows if that is the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Note: Windows 10 builds never started in 10240. It started in around the 9000's. I participated every windows 10 technical preview since the first.

Comment: I edited my post to clarify what I meant, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with my Win 10 upgrade as well (dualboot with Ubuntu 16.04).

I went to microsoft.com and chose to update my Win 10.
I downloaded the auto-update software (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) and the rest was done automatically.